# How to solve 'youtube link cors problem' via javascript ajax?

Tags: javascript, ruby, ajax, youtube, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to request the status code of a Youtube link via Javascript AJAX.(I want to check if the video has been deleted or still remains)

But when I try to request the status code, I receive following error message in browser console.

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.youtube.com/~~~' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

So.. how can I solve this problem ? My operating server consists of ruby on rails.

Thank you!

```
$.each(contentUrls, function(i, item) {
  $.ajax({
    crossOrigin: true,
    url: item,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function() {
      $('#valid' + i).html('V');
    },
    error: function(err) {
      console.log(err.statusCode);
      $('#valid' + i).html('X');
    },
  });
});
```

Comment: For local development, check out the CORS plugins on your browser plugins marketplace, alternatively, I'd strongly recommend not making the request via your browser. Send your request to your RoR server, which then makes the request to youtube

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby is not the issue here. The issue is that you're trying to AJAX into a different domain from the one you're calling from.

Try changing the datatype to `dataType: "jsonp"`, which will append a callback.

```
$.each(contentUrls, function(i, item) {
  $.ajax({
    crossOrigin: true,
    url: item,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function() {
      $('#valid' + i).html('V');
    },
    error: function(err) {
      console.log(err.statusCode);
      $('#valid' + i).html('X');
    },
  });
});
```

Check out https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ in the **DataType** section.